# In TYPO3, reintroduce page.includeJS with config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1

Tags: typo3, typoscript

To get clean Markup, I have set

```
page.config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
```

in TYPO3 6.1

This allow full control over the template, but also disables functionalities like page.includeJS, page.includeJSFooter etc. Basically, this is intended - but is there a way to bring back that functionality (e.g. when an extension uses it) and reintroduce the generated code punctually into the template?

Something like

```
page.10.marks.JSFOOTER < page.includeJSFooter
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically impossible, see https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Page/PageGenerator.php#l237

When disableAllHeaderCode is set, the content isn't wrapped at all with the header information. Since the header data is built on runtime, you cannot store it and re-use it.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think the main issue  that made me do it was introducing the paul irish conditional comments for ie. And I don't like CMSes writing HTML pages on their own ...